# How do I Share Audio into My iOS App and what to do about Unable to Share error?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to share a voicemail into my app.

To get the process down, I found a Medium article: https://medium.com/macoclock/ios-share-extension-swift-5-1-1606263746b , on how to implement the share extension, using photos.

My strategy was to get that in place, since there were no instructions online of how to do it with audio, hitting the file sent to my project with a breakpoint.

Trouble arose when I had understandably read the blogs steps, implemented the code, and ceased to have the breakpoint in the ShareViewController file hit, after running in Simulator and side loaded iPhone.

Questions:

- How do I share audio? What is the file type I need to identify in the Share View Controller?
- How do get past the "Unable to Connect" error?

My steps were:

1. add new target
2. Select Share extension
3. (add to Share plist) NSExtensionAttributes Dictionary, (then) NSExtensionActivationRule Dictionary, (then) NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount Number 1
4. Select the share scheme and device (either iPhone 8 plus simulator or local iPhone)
5. Click run with breakpoints on
6. Select Photos app to open
7. Click a photo, click My App from the Share sheet
8. Get alert ( title: "Unable to Share", message: "There was an error while preparing to share...")

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

@objc(ShareExtensionViewController)
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.handleSharedFile()
  }
  
    private func handleSharedFile() {
      // extracting the path to the URL that is being shared
      let attachments = (self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []
      let contentType = kUTTypeData as String
      for provider in attachments {
        // Check if the content type is the same as we expected
        if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
          provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType,
                            options: nil) { [unowned self] (data, error) in
          // Handle the error here if you want
          guard error == nil else { return }
               
          if let url = data as? URL,
             let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
               self.save(imageData, key: "imageData", value: imageData)
          } else {
            // Handle this situation as you prefer
            fatalError("Impossible to save image")
          }
        }}
      }
    }
      
    private func save(_ data: Data, key: String, value: Any) {
      let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
      userDefaults.set(data, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Here is my plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ACI-Share</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in all this, but I have finally managed to get my app to be able to share audio files (.mp3s).   The problem was that the share extension isn't really for audio files.  It's really for pictures and social media sites. If you share audio you have to put your app and your app extension into your own, app group.  Then when you share the audio, copy the audio from the containing app's documents folder to one shared by the app extension and then it can read it.   Anyway, that is what solved my problem.
Here is a link that helped me: [www.invasivecode.com](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions)

Comment: Article on Using App Groups to share with Widgets — https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/sharing-data-between-apps-and-their-extenstions/